# Export content inside textarea to Html not working on Internet Explorer 11

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, web, web-applications

The Javascript function to export content of textarea to html file is not working on Internet explorer 11 but it's working on other browsers. It's taking file name from radio button value (as 'Output.html'). I'm attaching the Javascript function:

```
function saveTextAsFile(){
    "use strict";
    var textToWrite = document.getElementById("codeToSave").value;
    var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite], {type:'text/html'});
    var fileNameToSaveAs = $('input:radio[name=exp-opt]:checked').val();

    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
    downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
    if (window.webkitURL != null){
        // Chrome allows the link to be clicked
        // without actually adding it to the DOM.
        downloadLink.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
    }
    else
    {
        // Firefox requires the link to be added to the DOM
        // before it can be clicked.
        downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
        downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
        downloadLink.style.display = "none";
        document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    }

    downloadLink.click();
}

function destroyClickedElement(event){
    "use strict";
    document.body.removeChild(event.target);
}
```

Comment: Can you add the error, or some console output to get more information about your issue

Comment: SCRIPT5: Access is denied.
File: template-js.js, Line: 324, Column: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try something like that:

```
function saveTextAsFile(){
    "use strict";
    var textToWrite = document.getElementById("codeToSave").value;
    var textFileAsBlob = new Blob([textToWrite], {type:'text/html'});
    var fileNameToSaveAs = $('input:radio[name=exp-opt]:checked').val();

    var downloadLink = document.createElement("a");
    downloadLink.download = fileNameToSaveAs;
    downloadLink.innerHTML = "Download File";
    // IE
    if (window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob) {
        $(downloadLink).click(function(){
            window.navigator.msSaveOrOpenBlob(textFileAsBlob, fileNameToSaveAs);
        });
    // Chrome
    } else if (window.webkitURL != null){
        // Chrome allows the link to be clicked
        // without actually adding it to the DOM.
        downloadLink.href = window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
    // FF
    } else {
        // Firefox requires the link to be added to the DOM
        // before it can be clicked.
        downloadLink.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(textFileAsBlob);
        downloadLink.onclick = destroyClickedElement;
        downloadLink.style.display = "none";
        document.body.appendChild(downloadLink);
    }

    downloadLink.click();
}
```

There is a jQuery tag in your question, so I used jQuery, but you can handle it in pure JavaScript if you prefer avoiding jQuery.